# Is there any comercial application written in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: programming-languages, .net, vb.net

In my work the language used to write applications is Visual Basic .NET.

I read on internet and almost all the examples and questions are about C#.

Is there any comercial application written in Visual Basic .NET? Is there any field for a VB Net developer?

Comment: As mentioned in the posts, C# may have a bigger market. Also, lots of books and tutorials use C#. C# is not very difficult to learn, at least the basics are not hard.

Comment: This is really just a survey question.

Comment: The Mono VB.NET Compiler was written in VB.NET, interestingly. http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support

Comment: Another VB.NET vs C# question. Due to C# bias, this question still open. Let's see if someone put it in reverse position. I expect ...

Comment: An important point to remember is that most of the base class libraries of .NET are written in C# so that even if your app itself is written in VB.NET, the libraries that it sits on are actually mostly written with C#.NET, and all of which compiles down to the same CLR bytecode format anyway, regardless of which .NET language was used.

Comment: @dodgy_coder: Citation needed for `most of the base class libraries of .NET are written in C#`

Comment: @Sweety: as requested ... [SO1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324919/what-language-is-net-framework-written-in/1324955#1324955), [SO2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062980/in-which-language-net-framework-has-been-written/3062990#3062990). PS: this has the assumption that [JaredPar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) with 100k+ rep knows what he's talking about ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your question is related to whether you can get a job as a VB.NET developer.

You can get VB.NET jobs, they do exist - but don't restrict yourself by something as unimportant as a language. Learn C# and then you can choose from a much bigger range of jobs. All of your understanding of the .NET framework is immediately useful if you switch to C#, so it becomes a simple exercise of learning the syntactical differences.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty actually. I don't know why, but some companies chose VB.net over C#, probably because they used to be VB shops, possibly because they feel VB.net is a better language (!)

I know of a very large design suite that is used for oil platform and ship building that has a large part written in vb.net.
I know nearly all the health system software for the UK NHS is written in VB.NET now.

The difference between C# and VB is tiny, VB has a few really cool features in there that makes it a better language that C# all in all, it's just that most people don't like its syntax.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what cool feature makes you believe that VB.NET is a better language than C#?

Comment: XMLliterals, checked exceptions (my favourite), and aggregate linq keyword (http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/09/LINQ-Aggregates). It's also better at COM interop.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: I'd say as of C# 4 they are comparable in terms of COM interop.

Answer (score 5):

VB.net and C# compile to the same CLR so the difference between them is quite small (some data structures etc)

For commercial applications as gbjbaanb mentioned, the NHS uses a lot of VB applications and this is also true across most of the UK public sector.

Answer (score 3):

There certainly are jobs out there for VB.NET developers. I interviewed with two companies just last year that use VB in their commercial applications. One is a major healthcare  IT provider that uses it almost exclusively although they are slowly migrating to C#. The other is a company that develops software for nonprofits, using VB in some of their web applications.

So it's not as popular as C#, and it may be a shrinking field, but you can still find jobs out there.

Answer (score 3):

I've worked on two vertical market desktop applications that were written in VB.NET. They had a user base of between 2000-3000 users each. One of these was in the healthcare filed and, from what I've seen, VB.NET remains a popular choice in this area.

I've also worked on a number of internal corporate VB.NET applications, both desktop and ASP.NET based. Jobs are out there but C# is more popular.